# Symbol's Position is wrong CSS

Tags: html, css

I believe I am overlooking something very easy but I can't seem to find the problem.

On my *Create* view I have code like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Total, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10 required">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Total, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Total, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now on the 2nd `div` I have a css class name called `required` and here are the specs on that:

```
.required:after{
    content: "*";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

Now here is how it renders:

[image: Issue]

How do I make the red asterisk appear right after the text-box? What am I missing in my CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.required:before`

```
   .required:before{
    content: "*";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    float:left;
}
#input{
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: I just tried that and that doesn't put the asterisk after the text box. it puts the asterisk above it and actually pushes the textbox down a little

Comment: the float: left brought the asterisk down, but where do i put the ID of input?  I tried putting `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Total, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "input", @class = "form-control" } })` and added #input{ float: left} in my CSS but it didn't change

Comment: Add 'float:left ' for label also

Comment: I just figured it out. see my solution to see what worked for me.  thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

CSS:

```
.required:after{
content: "*";
font-weight: bold;
color: red;
float:left;
margin-left: 5px;
}

#input{
    float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Total, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10 required">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Total, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "input", @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Total, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>
```